# When creating a linear model, how to specify a categorical variable?

Tags: r

So I'm trying to create a linear model representation of the following:
[image]

So, `Age.Category` is a categorical variable with the possible values of `Young Adult, Adult, Middle Age, and Senior.`

So I want to do something like this:

```
myModel = lm(Brozek ~ Weight + Age.CategorySenior:Thigh + Age.CategoryMiddle Age:Forearm + Age.CategorySenior:Wrist + Weight:Thigh + Abdomen:Thigh + Abdomen:Wrist, data = bodyfat)
```

but of course that won't work, so how do I make it happen?

Comment: lm() will usually handle categorical variables (factors) automatically.  What are Forearm, Wrist etc?  Are they dummy variables, or levels of a variable?

Comment: Hi @david25272, Age.Category is the only factor variable. Forearm, and wrist are numerical variables specifying a size. 

I understand that lm() automatically handles categorical variables, but assuming I'm only given the picture above, how can I convert that to a useable lm() object?

Comment: Normally you can just use Age.Catgeory:Thigh, that will give you an interaction between every age category with the Thigh variable.